# Highlight td elements with events

Tags: php, loops, datetime

I am generating a calendar via `PHP date()` function, I also have an ***events*** table that has a `name` and `date_start`, what I want to do is to highlight the td elements that have events on them and leave the ones without with the basic formatting.

**Basically, this is the script that loops the day:**

```
<?php
     echo "<tr>";

     for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++) { 
          $timeStamp = strtotime ("$year-$month-$i");
               if($i == 1){ 
                    $firstDay = date ("w", $timeStamp);
                    for ($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++){ 
                         //blank space
                         echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                    }     
                } 
                if($counter % 7 == 0 ){ 
                     echo "<tr></tr>";  
                }

                $todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
                if (date("Y-m-d", $timeStamp) == $todayDate) {
                ?>
                     <td class="today-date"><a href=""><?php echo $i; ?></a></td>
                <?php
                } else {
                ?>
                     <td><a href=""><?php echo $i; ?></a></td>
                <?php
                }
           }
           echo "</tr>";
?>
```

`.today-date` is a class to highlight the current day. This is my table columns:

```
id | name | description | date_start | date_end | time | pastor_id | pastor | category | venue
```

Comment: And what's your querstion / issue ?

Comment: @Meloman I cannot seem to get my head around on how to check the database for an event and use it as a parameter on an if condition to output a highlighted td element

Comment: Am I correct to assume that in your events database, if there's no event on a day you do not input a value? If that's the case, when you're creating your calendar, query the database with the date in your loop. If there's a result and the count > 0, then there's an event on that day..

Comment: have you got an example of your "events" table structure ? If yes, could you please add it to your question ? and what do you use for mySQL queries... PDO, mysqli ?

Comment: @WillParky93 yes, what I would want to do is that if there is no event in the database, there will be no class added BUT if there is, there should be a class somewhat like .event-class

Comment: @Meloman I have edited my post

Comment: @WillParky93 it worked with this concept, thank you very much

Comment: @thraxxdv You can see solution under... I hope it helps. My syntax has not been tested, hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably put my events into an array with a key for the start date, so you end up with something like:

```
$events = [
    '2017-08-22' => [
        'name' => 'Event Title',
    ],
    '2017-08-28' => [
        'name' => 'Event Title',
        'name' => 'Event Title',
    ],
];
```

There are multiple ways of doing this from a DB. Something like this:

```
$events = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($eventQuery))
{
    $events[$row['start_date']][] = $row['name'];
}
```

Then in your loop, you can check the date for an event and put it in:

```
<td class="<?php echo (array_key_exists(date("Y-m-d", $timeStamp), $events)) ? 'has-event-class' : ''; ?>">
```

Making database queries for every day in the calendar will be very inefficient compared to pulling all, or even the months'.

I would also be inclined to move this into a function so it's not as long in your loop:

```
function highlightEventTD($timeStamp, $events)
{
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $timeStamp);
    return (array_key_exists($date, $events)) ? 'has-event-class' : '';
}
```

Then in your forloop:

```
<td class="<?php echo highlightEventTD($timeStamp, $events); ?>">
```

It also means that if you need to show the name of the event, you can use the same array and a function:

```
function getEvents($timestamp, $events)
{
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $timeStamp);
    return (array_key_exists($date, $events)) ? $events[$date] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, PHP7 doesn't like anymore open and close php tag many times... I changed syntax with echo.

So try this :

```
// here make a SQL query (only one query is enough) 
// on your database, for example :
$dates = array();
$q = "SELECT * FROM `events`";
if($res = $pdo->query($q) {
    if($res = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        if(sizeof($res) > 0) {
            foreach($res as $k => $d) {
                $events[$d['date_start']] = $d;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<tr>";

for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays + 1; $i++, $counter++) { 
     $timeStamp = strtotime ("$year-$month-$i");

     if($i == 1){ 
          $firstDay = date ("w", $timeStamp);
          for ($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++) { 
              echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; //blank space
          }     
     } 

     if($counter % 7 == 0 ) { 
         echo "<tr></tr>";  
     }

     if (date("Y-m-d", $timeStamp) == date("Y-m-d")) {
         $class = "today-date ";
     }

     if (array_key_exists(date("Y-m-d"), $events)) {
         $class .= "event-date ";
     }

     // 1. solution based on your code
     echo "<td class=\"$class\"><a href=\"\">$i</a></td>";

     // 2. alternative with events in each day :
     echo "<td class=\"$class\">";
     if(sizeof($eventsOfTheDay = $events[$d['date_start']]) > 0 {
         foreach($eventsOfTheDay as $k => $event) {
             echo '<a href=?event_id="', $event['id'], '">', $event['name'], '</a><br>';
         }
     }
     echo "</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
```